# ViewFlipper vs AdapterViewFlipper

Tags: android

Could someone explain the practical differences between `ViewFlipper` and `AdapterViewFlipper`. Including when to use one and not the other.

I have been using `ViewFlipper` for months now in a custom cursor adapter and I am beginning to think I used the wrong approach albeit it works.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With `ViewFlipper`, you typically declare all children up front, and there is no recycling concept.

With `AdapterViewFlipper`, you use an `Adapter`, as you would with `ListView`, `Spinner`, etc., so the children are determined on the fly and the views representing the children can be recycled.

For small, static content, `ViewFlipper` is simpler. Also, `AdapterViewFlipper` was added in API Level 11 (IIRC) and therefore will not work on older versions on Android.

Comment: exist or you know some implementation of AdapterViewFlipper for Api Level < 11

Comment: @rkmax: `AdapterViewFlipper` was created mostly for use with app widgets. Since a backport still could not be used with app widgets, I am not aware of anyone who has bothered trying to backport it. That being said, you can grab the source code and try to backport it yourself.

Comment: I created [this](https://github.com/arichiardi/ava-project) project to port AdapterViewFlipper (and AdapterViewAnimator) to old Androids but I couldn't make it work inside App widgets. No problem for normal layouts. Have a look (sorry for the shameless self-promotion here).